# C# DataTable Column Mapping Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable, user-defined-types

1. I have data table `answersTbl` in C# populated with data
2. I have user-defined table type `UploadedAnswers` in SQL Server
3. I'm sending `answersTbl` as a `UploadedAnswers` parameter to a stored procedure

Values of columns in `answersTbl` are correct ([image: [pic 1]]), but after sending it to the stored procedure, the values do not match their columns.

```
select * from @UploadedAnswers
```

Returning this query back from stored procedure I can see not matching values ([image: pic 2])

The reason is that the order of adding columns to data table by me does not match the order of columns in the user-defined table type.

Is there any other solution or the order in C# and SQL should be same?

Comment: What's the `create` script for your table type?

Comment: How are you passing the TVP, is it a `DataTable`, do the columns have names and correct types? Please show C# code

Comment: @Charlieface
The names and types are correct. The only difference is order in C# DataTable Columns adding and SQL user-defined table type. It was mapped by order of types.

Comment: Looks like it's an issue inherent with `SqlClient` not just Dapper https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/306